Visual Studio 2022 not hitting breakpoints in WCF service file (.svc) but breakpoints work in unit tests
I'm experiencing an issue where Visual Studio 2022 is not hitting breakpoints in a file (an .svc file) of my WCF project, even though the code changes are reflecting correctly and the breakpoints work in unit tests.
When I run my WCF application in debug mode, the breakpoints I've set in the .svc file are not being hit, but symbols have loaded and the debugger seems to be skipping over them. However, breakpoints in other parts of the project, like unit tests, are working correctly.
Please let me know If have to share anything else that will help understand the problem more clearly.
Below are the steps I have tried in order to solve the issue.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution multiple times.
I've checked my debug settings and ensured they're configured correctly.
I've restarted Visual Studio and my computer.
I've verified that symbols are loading correctly.
I've disabled any third-party extensions in Visual Studio.
I've created a new project, and debugging works as expected in the new project.


For your problem, there is a relevant solution in MSDN. I think you should fit one of the reasons: if the source file has changed, but the source code hasn't been rebuilt, the debugger might not be able to set a breakpoint in the code. Try rebuilding your project by saving the source files again, or by cleaning up the build output before building.
